# How to activate the background div element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have two div elements, box_1 and box_2:

```
<div id="box_1" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:500px;height:500px;border:1px solid gray;z-index:2;">
</div>

<div id="box_2" onclick="alert(1);" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:300px;height:300px;background-color:red;z-index:1;">
how to activate me?(do not inner #box_1,and z-index less than box_1)
</div>
```

Check it >>> [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2kDqV/)

How to activate box_2 ? (do not inner #box_1,and z-index less than box_1)

activate == show alert(1) when click box_2

Comment: Can you define what you mean by "activate"?

Comment: activate == show alert(1) when click box_2, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't fully understand your question. The way you've got those boxes styled, the only way to get that `<div>` to be clickable is to give it a "z-index" value larger than 2.

Alternatively, you could give the *other* `<div>` a "z-index" value less than 1, or hide it.

If you can't change the markup, then the only thing you can do is catch events on the top `<div>` and forward them to the covered-up `<div>`.  That's pretty easy with jQuery — just add handlers to the top `<div>` and use ".trigger" to forward the events.

*edit* — like this maybe:

```
$('#box_1').click(function() {
  $('#box_2').trigger('click');
  return false;
});
```

Now that's going to catch events from all over the top `<div>`. You could check the event mouse coordinates to see whether they're inside the bottom `<div>` before triggering the event.

Comment: i can't change z-index,and i can't hide box_1,can i activate box_2?

Comment: No, you cannot. But you can sort-of "fake it".

Comment: I describe how in the answer above. You can attach an event handler to the top `<div>` and then forward the events to the bottom one.

Comment: You will get your requirement by just removing z-index property from both div

Answer (score 0):

You've done the right thing except box_1 is transparent so box_2 is showing through. If you give box_1 a background color like blue you'll see it appears on the top.

```
<div style=";width:500px;height:500px;border:1px solid gray;z-index:2;background:blue;" id="box_1">
</div>

<div style="width:300px;height:300px;background-color:red;z-index:1;" id="box_2" onclick="alert(1);">
how to activate me?(do not inner #box_1,and z-index less than box_1)
</div>
```